# Most efficient way to generate three numbers that are all different

Tags: arrays, random, comparison

I need to generate three random numbers each from 1-9 and each number mustn't match any of the others. I am doing this at the moment with the script below which works fine but was wondering if there is any other more efficient way to do this?

```
$rndn1 = 0;
$rndn2 = 0;
$rndn3 = 0;
while ($rndn1 == $rndn2 || $rndn2 == $rndn3 || $rndn1 == $rndn3) {
  $rndn1 = rand(1,9);
  $rndn2 = rand(1,9);
  $rndn3 = rand(1,9);
}
```

Also, using a simple expression as above could get complicated if for example 4 or more numbers needed to go through the same process.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a random permutation of numbers from 1-9 and then choose first 3 numbers, or if needed 4... etc...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation#Knuth_shuffles

try using this alg. to create the permutations.

This solution is scalable both on the range of numbers and on the qty of elements you need to choose. as long as the range of numbers (e.g 1-9) is unique this solution will not give you repetitions on the 3 numbers you choose.

Comment: If you only need three from nine, then there is no need to shuffle all nine.  Just shuffle enough to get three numbers, and leave the remaining six as they are - you won't be using them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate the three numbers each time.

Here's a first step :

```
$rndn2 = 0;
$rndn3 = 0;
$rndn1 = rand(1,9);
while ($rndn1 == $rndn2 || $rndn2 == $rndn3 || $rndn1 == $rndn3) {
  $rndn2 = rand(1,9);
  $rndn3 = rand(1,9);
}
```

And obviously you can do further :

```
$rndn1 = rand(1,9);
$rndn2 = rand(1,9);
while ($rndn1 == $rndn2) {
 $rndn2 = rand(1,9);
}
$rndn3 = rand(1,9);
while ($rndn2 == $rndn3 || $rndn1 == $rndn3) {
  $rndn3 = rand(1,9);
}
```

Don't try to optimize too much without profiling, through. This usually isn't needed. And the only operation that may be costly is the rand one : this is the one you must minimize (so don't generate more numbers before you test if you're just looking for 3 numbers (the problem would be different with more)).

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. I think the one from 'dystroy' will probably be easiest to implement at the moment but I'll look into the permuations option as it will allow scalability. Thanks again.